# Is MSMerge_History.time in GMT or local server time?

Tags: sql-server, replication, merge-replication

Is the time column in the [MSMerge_History](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-nz/library/ms187379.aspx) table GMT or local distribution server time?

Answer (score 1):

The [MSmerge_history table](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-nz/library/ms187379.aspx) does have a column named `time` and it's of the type `datetime`, it just isn't documented.

To answer your question, based on my tests it appears to be local server time.  The `time` column has a default value of `getdate()`.